# How does setuptools add modules to the runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I'm new to Python and overwhelmed with documentation regarding modules, package modules and imports.

Best I can understand, there are no "packages", only modules and import mechanisms and the officially recommended high-level API is provided by`setuptools` whose `Distribution` class is the key element that drives what and how modules are added to the runtime module import mechanism (sys.path?) but I'm lost in the details of things.

My understanding is that `setup.py` is a normal Python module that indirectly uses runtime API to add more modules while being executed before actual "user" code. As a normal module it could download more code (like installers), sort dependencies topologically, call system linker etc.

But specifically, I'm having difficulty in understanding:

- How `setup.py` decides whether to shadow system modules (like `math`) or not
- How `setup.py` configures the import mechanism so that above doesn't happen by accident
- How does `-m` interpreter flag work in comparison?

For conciseness, let's assume the most recent `CPython` and standard library only.

EDIT:

I see that `packages` are real, so are `globals` and `levels` as seen in [__import__ function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__). It appears that `setuptools` has control over them.

Answer (score 0):

`setuptools` helps packaging the code into the right formats (example: `setup.py build sdist bdist_wheel` to build the archives that can be downloaded from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/)) and then unpacking this code unto the right locations (example: `setup.py install` or indirectly `pip install`) so that later on it can be picked up automatically by Python's own import mechanisms (typically yes, the location is one of the directories pointed at by `sys.path`).

---

I might be wrong but I wouldn't say that:

> `setup.py` decides whether to shadow system modules (like `math`) or not

nor that:

> `setup.py` configures the import mechanism so that above doesn't happen by accident

As far as I know this can really well happen, there's nothing to prevent that and it is not necessarily a bad thing.

---

> How does -m interpreter flag work in comparison?

Instead of instructing Python interpreter to execute the code from a Python file by its path (example: `python ./setup.py`) it is possible to instruct the Python interpreter to execute a Python module (example: `python -m setup`, `python -m pip`, `python -m http.server`). In this case the Python will look for the named module in the directories pointed at by `sys.path`. This is why `setuptools`/`setup.py` and `pip` install the packages in a location that - if everything is configured right - is in `sys.path`.

I recommend you have a look at the values stored in `sys.path` by yourself, with for example the following command: `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`.